# Why isn't my image changing with the sprite?

Tags: python, pygame

I've made it so that the image for the Frisk sprite is determined by the player input via the arrow keys in player_input(self). Also, frisk_anim(self) is meant to animate the sprite. However, the sprite isn't being animated and the image isn't being changed via the player input. Any idea why this could be?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("UNDERRUNE")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() #updates which keys are being pressed

class Frisk(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        friskd1 = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_d1.png').convert_alpha())
        friskd2 = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_d2.png').convert_alpha())
        friskd3 = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_d3.png').convert_alpha())
        friskd4 = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_d4.png').convert_alpha())
        self.frisk_d = [friskd1,friskd2,friskd3,friskd4]
        friskr1 = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_r1.png').convert_alpha())
        friskr2 = pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_r2.png').convert_alpha()
        self.frisk_r = [friskr1,friskr2,friskr1,friskr2]
        frisku1 = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_u1.png').convert_alpha())
        frisku2 = pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_u2.png').convert_alpha()
        frisku3 = pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_u3.png').convert_alpha()
        frisku4 = pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_u4.png').convert_alpha()
        self.frisk_u = [frisku1,frisku2,frisku3,frisku4]
        friskl1 = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_l1.png').convert_alpha())
        friskl2 = pygame.image.load('assets/frisk_l2.png').convert_alpha()
        self.frisk_l = [friskl1,friskl2,friskl1,friskl2]
        self.frisk_index = 0
        self.walkframe = 0
        self.frisk_surf = [self.frisk_d[self.walkframe],self.frisk_r[self.walkframe],self.frisk_u[self.walkframe],self.frisk_l[self.walkframe]]
        self.image = self.frisk_surf

        self.image = self.frisk_surf[self.frisk_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (320,240))
        self.frisk_movedown = False

        self.vel = 5

    def player_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += self.vel
            self.frisk_surf = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += self.vel
            self.frisk_surf = 1
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= self.vel
            self.frisk_surf = 2
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= self.vel
            self.frisk_surf = 3
        if self.frisk_surf == 1:
            print("1")

    def frisk_anim(self):
        self.walkframe += 0.25
        if self.walkframe == 4:
            self.walkframe = 0

    def update(self):
        self.player_input()
        self.frisk_anim()

# GROUPS
frisk = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle() # group contains sprite
frisk.add(Frisk())

# GAME LOOP
while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    frisk.draw(screen)
    frisk.update()

    pygame.display.update() # updates the display surface
    clock.tick(60) # tells pygame that this while True loop shouldn't run faster then 60 fps
```

Comment: You're never updating the image. The sprite's draw method will render whatever the `image` attribute is, but you're never updating it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the image attribute when changing `walkframe` or `frisk_surf`:

```py
class Frisk(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        self.player_input()
        self.frisk_anim()
        self.frisk_surf = [self.frisk_d[self.walkframe],self.frisk_r[self.walkframe],self.frisk_u[self.walkframe],self.frisk_l[self.walkframe]]
        self.image = self.frisk_surf
```